# how to include Index in python Pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I am pivoting a dataframe.

```
df_features = df_features.pivot(index='filename', columns='code', values='frequency')
```

but when I do so the index field which is filename gets missing!

my dataframe is like this

```
filename  code  frequency
F1         X1       3      
F1         X2       6        
F1         X3       4
F2         X1       7
F2         X4       9
F3         X2       1
F3         X3       5
F4         X1       3
F4         X3       4
F4         X4       3
F5         X3       2
```

after Pivoting It should look like this

```
filename  X1   X2   X3   X4
F1        3    6    4    0
F2        7    0    0    9
F3        0    1    5    0
F4        3    0    4    3
F5        0    0    2    0
```

But what I acually Get is

```
X1   X2   X3   X4
3    6    4    0
7    0    0    9
0    1    5    0
3    0    4    3
0    0    2    0
```

my question is how to include filename in the pivoted dataframe?

Edit :

This is how the data look like in another example after pivoting

[image]

alothough I can see file name in the columns!!! yet when I try this code I get error

```
df_features["filename" ]


KeyError: 'filename'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename "key" is no longer a key, but an index.

`for i in df_features.index:
    print (i)`

This will give you your filenames. Does this help?

Comment: when i export the dataframe to a csv file there is no key or index !

Comment: Try the following: df_features.to_csv('test.csv', index=True, index_label='filename')

Comment: is there anyway I can keep filename as is in the dataframe after pivot

Comment: This is what I get from your original dataframe:

$ cat test.csv
filename,X1,X2,X3,X4
F1,3.0,6.0,4.0,0.0
F2,7.0,0.0,0.0,9.0
F3,0.0,1.0,5.0,0.0
F4,3.0,0.0,4.0,3.0
F5,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0

Comment: The comments leave something to be desired with respect to formatting. Imagine each comma-delimited list that begins with F1, F2, etc. as a new line.